# Derivative of $\sin^{-1}\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

How to find a complete expression for the derivative of $y=\sin^{-1}\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$

The graph of the function is:

[image: plot]

The derivative function is

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\begin{cases}\frac{2}{1+x^2}&\text{if }|x|\le 1\\\frac{-2}{1+x^2}&\text{if }|x|>1\end{cases}$$

**My Attempt**

```
Fullsimplify[D[ArcSin[(2*x)/(1 + x^2)], x]]
```

gives

$$-\frac{2\sqrt{\frac{(-1+x^2)^2}{(1+x^2)^2}}}{-1+x^2}$$

```
PowerExpand[-((2 Sqrt[(-1 + x^2)^2/(1 + x^2)^2])/(-1 + x^2))]
```

gives

$$-\frac{2}{1+x^2}$$

Why am I not getting the other part $\frac{+2}{1+x^2}$ ?.

How do I evaluate the derivative in cases like this ?

Comment: Does `FullSimplify[D[ArcSin[(2 x)/(1 + x^2)], x], x ∈ Reals]` suffice?

Comment: @CarlWoll for the given function we have both +ve and -ve derivatives, so i'd like to split the square root. Is it possible to do that?. and why does mathematica gives only one part of the solution for what i entered ?

Comment: @ss1729 `PowerExpand` ignores the fact that the square-root stands for positive square-root. Hence you lose that information in the simplified result. Carl Woll's solution is able to preserve that information using the signum function.

Comment: @Subho95 ok thanx. Carl Woll's suggestion is giving $$
\frac{\frac{-4 x^2}{(1 + x^2)^2} + \frac{2}{1+x^2}}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{4 x^2}{(1 + x^2)^2}}}
$$, but from that how do I reach the form $\frac{\pm 2x}{1+x^2}$ ?

Comment: @ss1729 This is strange. You should directly get $\frac{2* Sign[-1 + x^2]}{(1 + x^2)}$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
PiecewiseExpand[FullSimplify[D[ArcSin[(2 x)/(1 + x^2)], x], x ∈ Reals], x ∈ Reals]
```

[image]

Comment: `Assuming[Element[x, Reals], 
 D[ArcSin[2 x/(1 + x^2)], x] // Simplify // PiecewiseExpand]`

Comment: Thanx. So whats with $x\in \text{Reals}$ ?. How is it different ?

Comment: @ss1729. `FullSimplify[D[ArcSin[(2 x)/(1 + x^2)], x], x \[Element] Reals]` and now try:`FullSimplify[D[ArcSin[(2 x)/(1 + x^2)], x], x \[Element] Complexes]`
and what conclusions ?